# String received with utf8 format doesn't get displayed correctly

Tags: java, utf-8

I want to know how to receive the string from a file in Java which has different language letters.

I used `UTF-8` format. This can receive some language letters correctly, but Latin letters can't be displayed correctly.

So, how can I receive all language letters?

Alternatively, is there any other format which will allow me to receive all language letters.

Here's my code:

```
URL url = new URL("http://google.cm");

URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlc.getInputStream(), "UTF-8")); 
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(); 
int byteRead; 
while ((byteRead = buffer.read()) != -1)
{ 
    builder.append((char) byteRead);
} 

buffer.close();

text=builder.toString();
```

If I display the "text", the letters can't be displayed correctly.

Comment: What is the code you're using and how do you know that latin letters aren't being display "correctly"?

Comment: URL url = new URL("http://google.cm");

URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();

BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlc.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                                                                 
int byteRead;
 
while ((byteRead = buffer.read()) != -1)
{
 builder.append((char) byteRead);

}

buffer.close();
 
text=builder.toString();

if i display the "text" the letters cant display correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading a UTF-8 file is fairly simple in Java:

```
Reader r = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filename), "UTF-8");
```

If that isn't working, the issue lies elsewhere.

<s>EDIT: According to iconv, Google Cameroon is serving invalid UTF-8.  It seems to actually be iso-8859-1.</s>

EDIT2: Actually, I was wrong.  It serves (and declares) valid UTF-8 if the user agent contains "Mozilla/5.0" (or higher), but valid iso-8859-1 in (some) other cases.  Obviously, the best bet is to use getContentType to check before decoding.